# How to make a 15 sliding puzzle game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have created a game that has 16 spheres in it and they are swapping on mouse click. But I want to have 15 spheres and one empty gameobject, so as to make them slide with the help of an empty gameobject.and i also want to shuffle the spheres when game starts each time. How is it possible?

I follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuEYmFTKSAQ)

After that I tried to make it, but my cubes get overlapped on one another while changing their position on start.

```
var xtemp ;
    var ytemp ;



      var slot : Transform;




    var cubesPosition : Vector3[]  = new Vector3[16];

    var cubeGameObjects: GameObject[] = new GameObject[16];
        function Start () 
        {


           ChangePosition();
           AssignPositions();

        }  
        function ChangePosition()
        {
        for(var i=0;i<cubeGameObjects.length;i++)
        {
         cubeGameObjects[i].transform.position;
        }
         slot.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range (1,4),Random.Range (1,4),10);

        }

     function AssignPositions() 
     {
          for (var i = 0; i < cubesPosition.length; ++i)
          cubeGameObjects[i].transform.position = cubesPosition[i];
     }



     function OnMouseUp() {

    if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,slot.position)==1)
    {
    xtemp = transform.position.x;
    ytemp = transform.position.y;
    transform.position.x=slot.position.x;
    transform.position.y=slot.position.y;
    slot.position.x = xtemp;
    slot.position.y = ytemp;

    }
```

Comment: Try this tutorial instead... I think it is more suited to what your are after http://youtu.be/sSteq3uzICI

Comment: @  Savlon yes i follow it and i attach the material to each tile ,but in this tiles are not shuffling in the starting of game.,i want to make them shuffle

Comment: Ah I see... You do not say anything about shuffling the squares up in your actual question. Edit your original question asking for help with ahuffling

Comment: @ Savlon i asked that question too.,but as per your saying i update my question